# Syntax for reading an array in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array, stored in $array, that with

```
print "<pre>";
print_r($array);
print "</pre>";
```

gives an output like this:

```
Array
(
    [device] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Low volt light
                            [id] => 10
                            [type] => Z-Wave Switch Multilevel
                            [value] => 0
                            [address] => 00016922-018
                            [code] => 
                            [canDim] => True
                            [lastChange] => 26-07-2014 17:31:33
                            [firstLocation] => Kitchen
                            [secondLocation] => Main
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Light
                            [id] => 11
                            [type] => Z-Wave Switch Multilevel
                            [value] => 99
                            [address] => 00016922-019
                            [code] => 
                            [canDim] => True
                            [lastChange] => 31-07-2014 20:01:05
                            [firstLocation] => Bedroom
                            [secondLocation] => Main
                        )

                )
```

I cannot find my way to access/display for example the value (in this case 0) of device with  [id]=>10. What syntax would be the right one in php?

Comment: I think your array is not correct. think of changing it based on your requirement,

Comment: seeing the `@attributes` key makes me think this originated as xml. If that is the case, you can load the xml in one of the php xml classes and use xpath to query for specific nodes by their attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not an easy way to do this, without looping through the array.

e.g.

```
foreach ($array['devices'] as $device) {
    if ($device['@attributes']['id'] === $idBeingSearchedFor) {
        // Do something with $device.
    }
}
```

Due to the `@attributes` array key, I'm guessing that this came from XML at some point: You might consider using [Simple XML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) to parse it instead, as you could potentially use XPath then, which does support this type of access.

Alternatively again, you could reformat the array so it could be easily accessed by ID.

For example:

```
$formattedArray = array();

foreach ($array['devices'] as $device) {
    $id = $device['@attributes']['id'];
    $formattedArray[$id] = $device;
}
```

You could then access the device by its ID as follows:

```
$device = $formattedArray[$idBeingSearchedFor];
```

Comment: You don't even need to define the $id variable. :p

Comment: Correct: I just did it for readability in this instance.  The alternative way to write that line would be `$formattedArray[$device['@attributes']['id']] = $device;`

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like that:

```
$id = 10;
$device = array();
foreach($array['device'] as $devices) {
    if($devices['@attributes']['id'] == $id) {
        $device = $devices['@attributes'];
        break;
    }
}

echo $device['value'];
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like SimpleXML, and if that is the case then those arrays are actually objects that, when put through `print_r`, look just like arrays. To access them, do the following:

Get straight to the data:

```
$name = $array->device[0]->attributes()->name;
```

Or loop through each of the attributes in the first device:

```
foreach ($array->device[0]->attributes() as $key => $value) {
    // Do something with the data. $key is the name of the
    // attribute, and then you have the $value.
}
```

Or you could loop through all the devices:

```
foreach ($array->device as $device) {
    foreach ($device->attributes() as $key => $value) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: One of the reasons why I use var_dump() if I want to output something in order to see how it looks like.

Answer (score -1):

It's simple ... try below...

```
print $array['device'][0]['@attributes']['id'];
or
print $array['device']['0']['@attributes']['id'];
```

Comment: This assumes that the index of the device is known, which is not what the question asked: The question states that the search is based on the `id` attribute of the device.